# unable to create managed bean primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

this is the code of my managedBean class. i have no-arg constructor, setters and getters. still i'm unable to find what is wrong with the code.

i have added the managed bean in the faces-config file as well

```
public class TreeBean {

  private TreeNode root;

    public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }
<!--this is the no arg constructor.--!>
the setters and getters are also set accordingly.
   public TreeBean() {
      root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
      TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root); 
   }

   public TreeNode getRoot() {
      return root;
   }
}
```

when i run the xhtml file i throws the error as 
Unable to create managed bean treeBean. The following problems were found: - Bean or property class TreeBean for managed bean treeBean cannot be found.
what wrong have i done?

Comment: Please upvote the answer provided by van if you find it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you placed this `@ManagedBean(name = "treeBean")` in your TreeBean manage bean? cause base on the error you use **treeBean**. And maybe for safer code, try not to use similar name in your class and method, which in your case is the TreeBean. :)

Comment: thanks a lot van t the real prob was with netbeans. and yes ure answer was also helpful.